# ASP.NET creating resources at runtime

Tags: asp.net, resources, copy, multilingual

I'm developing an ASP.NET webapp that has a multilanguage feature allowing the webmaster to create new languages at runtime.

The approach that I was thinking is the following:

1. The user selects one available (not created) language.
2. When the user confirms, the application automatically copies a set of existing resources, replacing the filename with the new culture. For example: default.aspx.en-us.resx to default.aspx.es-ar.resx.
3. The user edits the recently created resources.

Currently I'm having troubles with step number 2. I've achieved to copy the resources, but then these new resources are ignored. I think that this happens because the new resources are not included in the running assembly, and therefore are being ignored.

When I test the following code in my local project, I would have to manually add the new resources to the solution and then recompile to make it work.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

This is the code of the mentioned copy.

```
string _dir = path_ + "App_LocalResources\\\\";
DirectoryInfo _dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(_dir);

foreach (FileInfo _file in _dirInfo.GetFiles("*en-us.resx")) {
_file.CopyTo(_dir + _file.Name.Replace("en-us", idioma_.Cultura));

}

string _dir2 = path_ + "App_GlobalResources\\\\";
_dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(_dir2);

foreach (FileInfo _file in _dirInfo.GetFiles("*en-us.resx")) {
_file.CopyTo(_dir2 + _file.Name.Replace("en-us", idioma_.Cultura));
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your project, what are the properties `Build Action`, `Copy To Output Directory`, `Custom Tool`, and `Custom Tool Namespace` set to for your .ResX files?

Comment: The default resx files have the following properties: Build acttion: "Content", Copy to output directory: "Do not copy", Custom tool: -nothing- , Custom tool Namespace: -nothing-

Comment: To complement my question, the copy process works OK. The problem is that after the copy, these new resource files are ignored and not read when I change the language.

Comment: I was curious because I did a test with the same settings.  I copied a new .resx file (global resource), and the new culture's text appeared when I refreshed the page.  I don't understand why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Did you copy it directly from the file system or did you the copy&paste inside the solution?. The code above generates the files but when I go to the solution explorer the new files are showed "excluded" from the project. If I include the files, it works. I will continue testing. Thank you for your responses

Comment: I copied in the file system -- did not touch the solution.

Comment: instead of copying the resx files to App_GlobalResources, can you just copy them to a new project, specifically created just to hold all resource files? you can then add the newly created resx files to the resources project by using Visual Studio automation framework. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Creating or editing Resource files is not possible the same way as reading data.
In order to create or edit a resource file, you should do it the same way you create or edit XML files because resource files have with a specific structured XML elements.

Maybe this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18368/Editing-a-Resource-File-Treating-It-as-an-XML-File) will help you...